# Ansible - combining data to get a single output or group

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and I have this data:

```
"d_list": [
        {
            "A": "string1",
            "B": "4",
            "C": "01"
        },
        {
            "A": "string2",
            "B": "4.00",
            "C": "02"
        },
        {
            "A": "string3",
            "B": "4.00",
            "C": "01"
        },
    ]
```

I need to combine data with same "c" field so that my target output is:

```
"c_list": [
        {
            "A": "string1", "string3"
            "B": "4",
            "C": "01"
        },
        {
            "A": "string2",
            "B": "4.00",
            "C": "02"
        }
    ]
```

I tried below:

```
- name: set
    set_fact:
      c_list: "{{ c_list | default({}) | combine(item) }}"
    with_items: "{{ d_list }}"
```

but i'm only getting the last item in d_list.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are combining an object with same keys every time (i.e. `{A: x, B: y, C: z}`). The result you describe is exactly what is expected, i.e. add new keys/values that do not exist, update existing keys with latest given values.

Comment: so I shouldnt use combine?  I thought it would combine the values of fields with same key.

Comment: how can i update data on existing keys in with_items?